# My 2011 Hyundai Genesis squeaks a lot

Tags: brake-rotor, squeaking, genesis-sedan

I have a 2011 Hyundai Genesis 4.6, I recently changed all 4 brakes and rotors, And it’s been about 2 weeks now and the front brakes are still squeaking really loud. At first it won’t squeak. But after about 10 minutes of driving, It’ll start squeaking a little bit, and than it’ll just louder and louder over time, usually when I’m braking at slower speeds.

Comment: Squeaking only when you brake?

Comment: Sounds like some metal/rust got caught somewhere it shouldn't have. Take it apart again and check for loose debris caught in the braking or suspension componenets.

Answer (score 1):

Low. Quality. Brake. Pads.

Replace them with ones from a reputable vendor. Replacing the pads only should not be expensive.

On the other hand, if it was your mechanic sourcing the parts, you should ask them to fix their mess.